# HP Z2 external power switch

Tags: motherboard, power, workstation, hp, external

I have in my workplace some HP Z2 workstation. Those computers have a non standard mother board, the power button is integrated on it.

Wanted to ask if outside of soldering extra wires to the button is there any way to connect a external power button?

Tried searching and didn't find anything that can work.

Comment: You could attempt it on one unit, but check that 1. The original switch is SPST. You could not simply wire a SPDT switch in parallel, as it would short outside contacts if on were pressed and not other. 2. Leads to added switch are kept short and routed away from electrical noise. 3. Soldering to the switch is possible in confines of PCB.